# Remote execution of shell commands

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm literally pulling my hair out here. I'm trying to create remote shell execution for my IRC bot, however, when I use commands such as "ls" or "cd" I'm getting a return of ": not found" , however, other commands such as mkdir or echo seem to work fine. The same goes for when I hard code commands, the output I get is exactly as it should be.

Can anyone see why? Here's my code:

```
            FILE *fp;
            int status;
            char path[1035];
            /* Open the command for reading. */
            fp = popen(ptr1, "r"); // hard code command and it works ????fp = popen("/bin/ls /etc/", "r");
            printf("%s", ptr1);//check received command (debugging)
            if (fp == NULL) {
                printf("Failed to run command\n" );
```

removed some code for ethical reasons.

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you provide us with sample input and what your program is expected to do based on that input. That is, what is `input` variable value like at the first line?

Comment: This is a great way to get yourself rooted....

Comment: input is the strings read into the bot client on IRC.
R: I understand that, and that's what I'm trying to research by doing this.

Comment: Does whoever is running this program have /bin in their path?  Are you passing /etc/ls in the command, or just 'ls'?

Comment: I've tried /bin/ls , /etc/ls and 'ls'. No luck except when it's executed in the code. Here are the results from echo $PATH:
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Now setting the path manually is not really seen as an ideal solution in this case, as hinted at earlier; I'm trying to remotely root boxes for a research project I'm working on. Can I set my path inside the code?                         sprintf("export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin;%s",ptr1);

Comment: Use `setenv` to set the environment.

Comment: Does it only work when you hardcode the command? Try checking if ptr1 points to correctly allocated memory and that the command string is null terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code above ptr1 isn't initialized.  Assuming ptr1 is your command and is populated elsewhere, have you checked if the string is zero terminated in the right spot? Even with the printf, some nonprintable characters may be between the end of your string and your zero termination so that you have "ls___". Just a quick sanity check on the ptr1 length might be in order:

`printf("%s : %lu", ptr1, strlen(ptr1));`

Answer (score 2):

I would guess from your error message that you have a spurious carriage return in the string that you are passing to popen.  So you are actually calling, eg `popen("ls\r", "r");` which is failing with the error message `ls\r: not found`.  When you print that error message, the carriage return causes it to skip back to the beginning of the line, looking like `: not found`

Carriage returns are a notorious source of odd errors like this, as they are NOT whitespace to the shell, but you can't really see them when you print them out.